# VB.Net Validate class properties with FluenValidation library

Tags: vb.net, fluentvalidation

Hi everybody I'm trying to use FluentValidation in VB.Net to validate properties of a simple class

This is the class:

```
 Public Sub New(ByVal descrizione As String, metristoppino As Integer, assortimento As Byte)
        ' Set the property value.
        Me.Descrizione = descrizione
        Me.MetriStoppino = metristoppino
        Me.Assortimento = assortimento
    End Sub
```

this is the rule:

```
            Sub()
                RuleFor(Function(x) x.Descrizione).NotEmpty()
                RuleFor(Function(x) x.Assortimento).LessThan(8)
            End Sub
        )
```

and this is the code with the validator call:

```
 Dim analisi As New AnalisiFF("", 150, 9)
 Dim Verificatore As New AnalisiFFValidator()
 Dim result As ValidationResult = Verificatore.Validate(analisi)
```

I tried .WithErrorCode("someerror") as well as .WithMessage("My Error Message") but I can't get the expected failing error.

Can anybody explain to me why I'm not getting an error with an empty string for 'Descrizione' and a value of 9  for 'Assortimento' ?

Thanks a lot

***UPDATE***
While adapting c# code to VB.Net I didn't noticed rules where part of a RuleSet.
Removing RuleSet allows correct validation performing.
Still to be understood is how to use RuleSet in VB.Net and the correct syntax for options while calling validate method